# SQL- row values for same id as list (,)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table as this:

```
id  |  code
111 |  IL
111 |  IN
222 |  UK
222 |  IN
```

I want this:

```
id  |  path
111 |  IL,IN
222 |  UK,IN
```

and furher that to count the distinct ids in different paths, thanks

Comment: Provide your DBMS (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle...)

Comment: SQL-server that would be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *SQL-Server* you can do in following:

**SAMPLE DATE**

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(id INT, code VARCHAR(40))
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES (111,'IL'),(111,'IN'),(222,'UK'),(222,'IN')
```

---

**QUERY**

```
SELECT  id
       ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(code AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
               FROM @Tbl 
               WHERE id = t.id
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
       .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') path
FROM @Tbl t
GROUP BY id
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
id   path
111  IL,IN
222  UK,IN
```